# inline asp.net in TextBox not compiling

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have created a jquery script, that makes a textbox as autoCompletebox, and it's working very well. 
For this script to work, I want to get the Value HiddenField ClientID in jqvalue and OnSelect trigger button in jqbutton.

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="vendorIDField" runat="server"   />
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  CssClass="jq-autocbox absfields" pos="c3 r2" igaddl="nofield" jqvalue = "#<%= vendorIDField.ClientID %>" jqcontainer = ".form-content" jqURL = "GetLists.ashx" jqcommand = "GetVendors" jqbutton = '#<%= Button2.ClientID  %>' Width="250px" ></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

But the ClientID is not compiling. In browser it appears like what I type inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value to attribute in code behind using Attributes collection.

```
TextBox1.Attribute["jqvalue"] = vendorIDField.ClientID;
```